# Uncaught exception: no application instance (blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry

Im trying to play an audio file using blackberry.
This line - clickplayer.realize(); is throwing an exception - "Uncaught exception: no application instance". I'm not sure why this is being thrown ?

```
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AudioPlayback a = new AudioPlayback();
                a.play();
            }
        });
```

This is the AudioPlayback class  -

```
public class AudioPlayback {

    public void play(){

        try {
        Player clickplayer = null;
        InputStream instream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jingle.wav");
        clickplayer = Manager.createPlayer(instream, "audio/x-wav");
        clickplayer.realize();
        clickplayer.setLoopCount(1);

        VolumeControl vc = (VolumeControl) clickplayer.getControl("VolumeControl"); 
        if (vc != null)
            vc.setLevel(100);

        clickplayer.prefetch();
        clickplayer.setMediaTime(0);
        clickplayer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to register the event dispatcher before  trying to play a sound. Below code fixes the issue where Driver is my own class that extends UiApplication.

```
Driver theApp = new Driver();
theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
```